# How to get private messages related to a particular user programatically?

Tags: module, drupal-7, private-messaging

I want to get private messages (provided by the [Privatemsg module](http://drupal.org/project/privatemsg)) that are related to a particular user, programatically.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private messages are entities so you can use `entity_load()` to load them by condition...or use the wrapper provided by the private message module itself:

```
$messages = privatemsg_message_load_multiple(array(), array('author' => $uid));
```

That will get all messages created by the user identified by `$uid`.

Comment: There's 3 or 4 different questions in there - this one's already been answered, I'd advise breaking what you need to do down into the remaining individual tasks and asking each as a separate question once you've exhausted your own research on the subject

Comment: I want to load conversation between a particular user and logged in user. Thanks. I need to know if there is any inbuilt function